# Why should I declare variable in the While loop

Tags: c++, variables, while-loop, declaration

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n, line_number = 1, stars = 1;
    cout << "Enter lines number " << endl;
    cin >> n;
    while (line_number <= n)
    {

        while (stars <= line_number) {

            cout << "*";
            stars++;
        }
        line_number++;
        cout << endl;
    }

}
```

*I've just started learning programming*
in this code to draw a right-angled triangle , when I declare the variable "stars" with the rest of variables , it's printing only 1 star in each line , to print another one in every line I have to declare it in the first while loop body , why does that happen ?

Comment: Hint: What is the value of `stars` in the two cases you just cited right *before* the following loop condition is encountered: `while (stars <= line_number)` ? And fyi, you don't *have* to declare it inside the first while loop. You can obtain the same behavior by simply resetting `stars = 1;` immediately before the previously mentioned most-inner loop begins. That in itself is probably an even bigger hint as to what is happening.

Comment: @BassemWanies , if you are satisfied with my answer, please mark it. Or if there is any confusion, let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable 'stars' you were using was incremented at the same pace as the variable 'line_number'.  For example, at line 1 the 'stars' with value of 1 was equal to the 'line_number' with value of 1 so the line 1 only print one '*' which is correct.  However from the line 2 and so on, due to the 'star' was incremented by 1 in second while loop and 'line_number' incremented by 1 in first while loop, both variable will incremented together with value 3,3 respectively, 4,4 respectively and so on so the second while loop for line 2 will compare (stars<=line_number) as (2<=2) so it will only loop for once.  To solve this issue you only need to reset the 'stars' value to 1 in the first while loop for the second while loop loop from 1 to the number of line.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to redeclare the variable `stars`. Just assign it the value 1. Because for each line you have to print **`as many ' * ' as the linenumber itself`**, that is it.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n, line_number = 1, stars = 1;
    cout << "Enter lines number " << endl;
    cin >> n;
    while (line_number <= n)
    {

        while (stars <= line_number) {

            cout << "*";
            stars++;
        }
        line_number++;
        stars = 1;
        cout << endl;
    }

}
```